# How do I search for connected elements in a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, networkx, graph-theory

I have a matrix in this form:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], columns = list('ABCDE'), index = list('ABCDE'))

In [2]:df
Out[2]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  0  1  1  1
B  0  0  0  1  0
C  1  0  0  0  0
D  1  1  0  0  1
E  1  0  0  1  0
```

The number 1 represents the connection between two elements. In this case 'A' is connected to 'D' and 'E' and 'D' are connected to 'E', forming a closed connection formed by three elements.
I look for the greatest number of elements connected to each other, in this case 'A', 'D', 'E'.
I could use for loops but it gets too slow for a 300x300 matrix. How can I solve?

Update 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], columns = list('ABCDEF'), index = list('ABCDEF'))
```

In this case the solution is the longest cycle ['D', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'E'].

Is it possible to have only full connected elements such as, in the case presented in the example, 'C', 'D', 'E'?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the actual elements or just the number of elements?

Comment: Actual elements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you appear to be looking for IIUC, from a graph theory point of view, are the [graph cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)). You can find the cycles by generating a graph from the adjacency matrix using `NetworkX`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue')
```

[image]

You can find the graph cycles via [`nx.simple_cycles`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html), and from there easily obtain the longest:

```
max(nx.simple_cycles(G), key=len)
# ['E', 'D', 'A']
```

---

**Update** -

If you want only fully connected elements in those "cycles", what you want are the graph [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)). You'll first have to convert to undirected, since `nx.find_cliques` isn't defined for directed graphs, and then find the `max` using `len` as a key function:

```
H = G.to_undirected()
nx.draw(H, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue')
```

[image]

```
max(nx.find_cliques(H), key=len)
# ['D', 'E', 'C']
```

Comment: The solution is ok but after 4 hours, on 244x 244 matrix, the process has not finished.

Comment: Guessing the complexity of the cycles functions is high, specially for highly connected graphs @GiovanniRuggieri quite surprised that it can take that long on an adj matrix of just that size though

Comment: You might find this thread insightful as to why it can get pretty slow https://groups.google.com/g/networkx-discuss/c/6FiQy-cxsBM?pli=1 @GiovanniRuggieri

Comment: I had tried it too but without using the len parameter. Can you explain me what the len parameter is for?

Comment: The parameter is for the `max` function. It finds the max, using the length of the iterables as a criteria to find the max.  @GiovanniRuggieri